# Ошибка совместимости при переходе на Unity 5

Tags: unity3d

При переходе на Unity 5 появились проблемы совместимости со старыми устройствами на Android. Например, на Asus Transformer появилась ошибка при запуске:

> "Hardware is not supported by this application".

На форумах везде пишут, что прекратилась поддержка устройств без

```
NEON CPU (Dropped support for non-NEON CPU devices (e.g. Tegra 2)).
```

Есть ли возможность как-то настройками вернуть ее? Вообще Unity 5 стал странным, на 4 версии apk файл весил 14 мб, на 5-ой стал почти 18.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

К сожалению настроить никак нельзя. На форумах по Unity разработчики пишут, что поддержки не будет, а тем, кто хочет поддерживать совместимость со старыми устройствами необходимо использовать Unity 4.

Comment: Примерный список устройств Вам не удалось получить? Или чипов без NEON